# Which context should I code for using "require" method

Tags: ruby

The programs below have the same behavior. What does `require` do in fact?
In both cases, I can use methods which are defined in `my_extension.rb`. But, which is better in ruby?

case1: use `requre` in class.

```ruby
class Foo
  require "my_extension"
end
```

case2: use `require` in toplevel.

```ruby
require "my_extension"

class Foo
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 2 is better, purely because it's proper etiquette and easier for other programs to find your code's dependencies.

Technically, `require` does the exact same thing no matter where you call it: it simply runs the code in the file. The only difference between placements is when (if ever) the `require` is actually called. For example:

```
def my_method
  require "my_extension"
end
```

In this case, `my_extension.rb` isn't loaded until `my_method` is called.